# Rotation argument for scikit-learn's factor analysis

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction, factor-analysis

One of the hallmarks of factor analysis is that it allows for non-orthogonal latent variables.

In R for example this feature is accessible via the `rotation` parameter of [`factanal`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/factanal.html).
Is there any such provision for [`sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html#sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis)? Clearly it's not among the arguments - but maybe there is another way to achieve this?

Sadly I have been unable to find many examples of usage for this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. I think there are no rotations implemented indeed - see [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2688).

Maybe [this implementation](https://github.com/mvds314/factor_rotation) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is now implemented.

Example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_varimax_fa.html

```
rotation{‘varimax’, ‘quartimax’}, default=None

If not None, apply the indicated rotation. Currently, varimax and 
quartimax are implemented. See “The varimax criterion for analytic 
rotation in factor analysis” H. F. Kaiser, 1958.

New in version 0.24.
```

Source: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html